# Writing to a file on disk using Airflow is not working

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I am using Windows machine and have created container for airflow.
I am able to read data on the local filesystem through DAG but I am unable to write data to a file. I have also tried giving full path, also tried on different operators: Python and Bash but still it doesn't work.
The DAG succeeds there isn't any failures to show.
Note: /opt/airflow : is the $AIRFLOW_HOME path

what may be the reason?

A snippet of code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


def pre_process():
    f = open("/opt/airflow/write.txt", "w")
    f.write("world")
    f.close()


with DAG(dag_id="test_data", start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 24), schedule_interval='@daily') as dag:
    check_file = BashOperator(
        task_id="check_file",
        bash_command="echo Hi > /opt/airflow/hi.txt "
    )
    pre_processing = PythonOperator(
        task_id="pre_process",
        python_callable=pre_process
    )
    check_file >> pre_processing
```

Answer (score 1):

It likely is written but in the container that is running airflow.

You need to understand how containers work. They provide isolation, but this also means that unless you do some data sharing, whatever you create in the container, stays in the container and you do not see it outside of it (that's what container isolation is all about).

You can usually enter the container via `docker exec` command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/ or you can - for example - mount a folder from your host to your container and write your files there (as far as I know, by default in Windows some folders are mounted for you - but you need to check docker documentation for that).

Comment: I am not able to see it inside the container. And yes, I have mounted the folders and using those to share files.

Comment: Then you might be checking wrong things, you must be doing some mistake when checking it. If you successully run the bash command, the file should be created in the container it was run. I think you just should try harder - experiment with exiting with error (to see if the bash is actually run), try to execute scripts rather than command, make mistakes in the commands to see if they actually error out. There is nothing obviously wrong with your code and I am afraid you are the only person that can help yourself by just experimenting and finding the wrong assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

In your pre_process code, add `os.chdir('your/path')` before write your data to a file.